# Creating videos of AI generated photographs

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, image-generation

I came across this article today: [These faces show how far AI image generation has advanced in just four years](https://www.theverge.com/2018/12/17/18144356/ai-image-generation-fake-faces-people-nvidia-generative-adversarial-networks-gans). I would never in a million years have guessed that the people on the right (in the first image in the article) were fakes! [image: [AI generated images (2014 on the left and 2018 on the right)]

Will it be possible to create videos of such AI generated images? What, then, will become of actors and actresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't really consider what they are doing as AI - they are using a script that intelligently overlaps various images of existing people in order to create a new face.

Animating those images isn't impossible - essentially extrapolation + additional "real" images will be used to know what the face would like from all angles and in all states (happy, sad, intrigued, etc...).

Comment: Fascinating! I would love to watch a Hollywood movie someday made without any human actors.

Comment: The Verge doesn't link to a paper, but the article mentions that Nvidia uses [Generative Adversarial Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network).

Comment: @Thomas That was also George Lucas' dream too, and it led him to build the industry that will make it so.  (Not specifically AI, but rendering and digital effects, which supported AI.  Industrial Light and Magic.)  Plus, he made us love robots.